# How to show custom Unit test data in sonar

Tags: sonarqube

I have a non Java based project which has several modules in it. Right now when the build is invoked, a proprietary written test suite runs and it publishes following data in a log file.

Number of total test cases run
Total number of successful test cases
Total number of failed test cases.

These three data can also be found per module level.

I was looking towards a way for storing and reporting this data in the way currently sonar does for its junit coverage reports. My intention of using Sonar is to get all reporting functionalities it provides by default like showing what has changed in a period of time or since last build, drilling down to module level etc.

Now the problem is, my data is not coverage report and my view ideally is also bit different from the default view sonar publishes.

My question is am i right in thinking of using Sonar to build such reporting functionality? If yes how should I approach this problem?

Do I need to write custom plugin for this or can I accomplish this somehow with custom metrics/measures?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do what you want with the [Generic Test Coverage](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Generic+Test+Coverage) plugin. It will import test data for any *known* file type (i.e. for any file extension that's recognized by a language plugin you have loaded), and all you have to do to use it is put your test result data into its simple XML format.

However, what you describe as having available is aggregate data: total # tests, total # successes, total # failures. What it is expecting is granular data: individual tests with either duration (success) or failure message.

If you're not able to expose the granular data, then yes, you may need to code your own plugin, but should be able to use the Generic Test Coverage plugin as a model.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Though this plugin doesn't cover what i want, but it looks to be a good guide for a custom plugin. I will try and update accordingly.